# Multiple Cloud Run local development

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm doing some test using Cloud Run in a local environment. Source code is [here](https://github.com/lorenzomar/test-google-cloud-run).

It is a really simple demo app made of 2 services that I execute on different port using gcloud cli:

```
hello-world
gcloud alpha code dev --builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1 --local-port=8080
```

```
hello-world-2
gcloud alpha code dev --builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1 --local-port=8081
```

I need to do an HTTP call from hello-world to hello-world-2.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you try to perform a call on `localhost:8081` from hello-world service?

Comment: Yes... It is what is done but it doesn't work because localhost resolve on itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gcloud CLI creates your builds as a service in your local Kubernetes cluster, when you execute the `gcloud alpha code dev` command. All services there is created in that way in a Kubernetes cluster will be exposed with a internal DNS name you can use from other services. So from your **hello-world** service can you communicate with the **hello-world-2** service on the URL: `http://hello-world-2:8080`

[image]